# VS 2012 sql compare tool as standalone

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, database-project

VS 2012 has an excellent support for comparing database projects and databases.

I'm wondering if there is a standalone version for the respective software to use on a deployment machine - or some other way to use it without having to install the whole of visual studio.

Comment: Look up how to do a headless install of SSDT (or just install the SSDT bits) assuming that you're using *.sqlproj files and not *.dbproj files for your projects.

Comment: @PeterSchott I was hoping to actually have the graphical diffing tool outside visual studio.

Comment: Well, the SSDT install by itself isn't the full VS 2012 install - it's the VS IDE w/ the SSDT bits. If you want something that doesn't use VS, you may want to look into Red Gate's SQL Compare. There's also the option to just use SQLPackage to do a diff and generate an XML file of what's different. It won't show you the details, but will give you an idea of what will change.

Comment: @PeterSchott Oh, you're saying that SSDT *does* come with a boiled-down version of VS?

Comment: Correct - it will download either the VS2012 or 2010 IDE (only) as part of the install. If you can't access the internet from you install location, you'll need to set up an Administrative Install point and then install from there.

Comment: @PeterSchott Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. If you write your comment as an answer, I accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install just the SSDT for SQL Project bits on a machine. That does not require a full install of either Visual Studio or SQL Server. You can generally keep an eye on the SSDT Blog for the latest release news.  You can find that at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

At this time, the most recent release is the October 2013 release.

As noted in the various articles, you may need to make an Administrative Install Point if your target machine does not have internet access. Follow the instructions in the article and you should be fine.

I've written some articles about this on my blog at http://schottsql.blogspot.com if you look up the label for SSDT.